# Having problem in comparing String with a List element

Tags: android, string, flutter, list, dart

I am trying to run an if-else condition that displays certain Icons based on the given conditions. I am trying to see if a particular quizId,i.e. a string is present inside the list to fulfill the condition. For some reason, the condition doesn't seem to work even though the element is present inside the list.

I have tried manually comparing the quizId with a particular String, which worked out fine. But as soon as I bring the list into the condition, it stops working. I have found both the quizId and List element data types which is String yet they still can't be compared.

This is the piece of Code :

```
class QuizBadge extends StatelessWidget {
  const QuizBadge({super.key, required this.topic, required this.quizId});

  final Topic topic;
  final String quizId;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Report report = Provider.of<Report>(context);
    List completed = report.topics.values.toList();

    List a = completed.expand((element) => element).toList();
    print(a[1]);

    if (a[1] == "flutter-basics") {
      return const Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.checkDouble, color: Colors.green);
    } else {
      return const Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.solidCircle, color: Colors.grey);
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank You.

Edited Code Piece :

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Report report = Provider.of<Report>(context);

    List completed = report.topics[topic.id] ?? [];
    String str = completed.map((e) => e.toString()).join('-');

    if (str.contains(quizId)) {
      return const Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.checkDouble, color: Colors.green);
    } else {
      return const Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.solidCircle, color: Colors.grey);
    }
  }
```

This seems to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is occurring because the elements in your list are not strings. Consider checking the type returned by `report.topics.values.toList()` (I can't tell because you didn't include this) and/or explicitly declare the lists you expect to be strings as `List<String>`, for example:

```dart
    List<String> a = completed.expand((element) => element).toList();
```

You will see an error on that line if you declare it this way, and the error will offer a clue.

In general, I prefer to avoid using generics without specifying an explicit type, because the default is `dynamic`, and you don't get the benefit of static type checking. You can also maintain explicit typing by using `var`/`final` declarations, such as:

```dart
    var a = completed.expand((element) => element).toList();
```

### Follow-Up

```dart
void main() {
  var completed = [["firestore-basics"], ["flutter-basics"], ["js-basics", "js-variables"], ["rxjs-basics"]];
  var a = completed.expand((element) => element).toList();
  print(a);
  bool contains = a.contains('flutter-basics');
  print('contains? = $contains');
}
```

Output:

```
[firestore-basics, flutter-basics, js-basics, js-variables, rxjs-basics]
contains? = true
```

Comment: Yes, this solved it. I converted the elements in the list to strings using map(). Thanks for the help!

Comment: One doubt tho. After reading your answer, I used ```List<String> a = completed.map((e) => e.toString()).toList()``` and then I placed ```a``` in the if condition but it doesn't seem to work even after the list is of the type List<String>. Any ideas for this?

Comment: What do you mean by "placed `a` in the if condition"?  If you want to check if *any* element in the list equals the string, then you should use `a.any((element) => element == "flutter-basics")`. I'm not certain about what exactly it is you're trying to do, otherwise I could offer a more precise suggestion.

Comment: ```if (a .contains( "flutter-basics")) {
      return const Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.checkDouble, color: Colors.green);
    } else {
      return const Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.solidCircle, color: Colors.grey);
    }
```
This is after making the variable ```a``` as a List<String>

Comment: Have you tried printing the contents of `a` (or using the debugger) to see if it is what you are expecting?

Comment: Yes I have. The output I am getting is this : 

[["firestore-basics"], ["flutter-basics"], ["js-basics", "js-variables"], ["rxjs-basics"]]

I can't seem to use the contains() method to check for a string in this list somehow.

Comment: Right, because that is a list of lists, not a list of strings, and `string != [string]`. Please see updated answer for a working example. Did you remove the `expand()`? I'm unclear what your code looks like now.

Comment: I have put my new code piece in the edited answer.